# Long term capital gains tax on equities in India

Tags: india, capital-gains-tax

Which of the following is applicable to long term capital gains on Indian stocks and on foreign stocks?

a) Long-term capital gains are subject to tax at 20%;

b) Long-term capital gains arising from transfer of listed securities, units or a zero coupon bonds shall be taxable at lower of following:

i. 20% after taking benefit of indexation; or

ii. 10% without taking benefit of indexation.

c) Long-term capital gains arising to a non-residents or foreign company from transfer of unlisted securities shall be taxed at without giving benefit for indexation;

d) Long-term capital gains arising from transfer of listed equity share, or a unit of an equity oriented fund or a unit of a business trust as referred to in Section 112A shall be chargeable to tax at the rate of 10% in excess of Rs. 1 Lakh.

Answer (score 0):

Indian stocks, Long term gains at 10% if the gains are more than Rs 1,00,000 in financial year.

Foreign stocks it would be taxed at the tax bracket.

Comment: Of the options for long term capital gains taxation, I don't see taxation at tax bracket anywhere. I see it only for short term capital gains.